# How to change only the last letter in a word using PHP's preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I want know how to use `preg_replace` to change `A` - when it is the last letter - to `e`.
For example, I want to change the word `"karema"` to `"kareme"` - notice only the last `a` has changed, not the one in the middle!

Answer (score 5):

For changing `"a"` at the end of every word, use `a\b`:

```
preg_replace("/a\b/", "e", $str);
```

`\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), it would work well in your case.

Example: http://ideone.com/ehN43

If your string is a single word you may also use `a$` - the `a` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only that specific word, you don't need `preg_replace`. Simply use `str_replace('karema', 'kareme', $TEXT_TO_BE_CHANGED)`. If this isn't what you want, you'll have to provide a more detailed example of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
preg_replace('/a\s/i', 'e ', 'This is some sample text karama dharama');
```

It will replace karama to karame and dhrama to dharame

Comment: That won't work for `karema.`, `karema,`, `karema!`, `"karema"`, or the many other cases where the final letter in a word is not followed by whitespace.

Comment: thanks but could you explan to me how i work? and pleas tell me good book learn me rgex ^^